# XML over REST - Is XML Header required?

Tags: xml, rest

A valid XML file requires a xml header.

However, if I send the XML over a RESTFul API, do I still have to set the header? At least firefox doesn't complain, but this might not be a valid metric.

Thank you, Johann

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use XML over REST then your XML should be fully compliant to be as interoperable as possible:

http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-prolog-dtd

The standard say "**should**", not "**must**" which makes it optional but advisable as a good practice.